# Convert date format in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, format

I need the date to show in this format 2014-11-04 as "yy mm dd"

Currently, my script still shows me 
Tue Nov 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var userDate = '04.11.2014';
    from = userDate.split(".");
    f = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
    console.log(f); 
});
```

Comment: Are you allowed to used moment.js ? Have a look here - http://momentjs.com/

Comment: jQuery has no utility function for dates.

Comment: i add moment plugin but i got lost, not sure how to combine the code with mine

Comment: to replace the dots with dashes, why not use a regex replace?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can construct this using the date object's methods

```
var date    = new Date(userDate),
    yr      = date.getFullYear(),
    month   = date.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth(),
    day     = date.getDate()  < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate()  : date.getDate(),
    newDate = yr + '-' + month + '-' + day;
console.log(newDate);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but still not what i need , has to show zero if month or day is a single number

Comment: Why is there a '+' sign before date.getMonth() and date.getDate()? Are these necessary?

Comment: @Anthony that's the unary plus operator. Its used to coerce the operands to a number, e.g. `+"3" === 3`. And no, IIRC those functions return integers anyway, so no they're not necessary.

Comment: just replace
    month   = date.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + date.getMonth() : date.getMonth(),
with
month   = (date.getMonth()+1) < 10 ? '0' + (date.getMonth()+1) : (date.getMonth()+1),

Answer (score 8):

You may try the following:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var userDate = '04.11.2014';
        var from = userDate.split(".");
        var f = new Date(from[2], from[1], from[0]);
        var date_string = f.getFullYear() + " " + f.getMonth() + " " + f.getDate();
        console.log(date_string);
    });
```

Alternatively I would look into  **[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)** It would be way easier to deal with dates:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var userDate = '04.11.2014';
    var date_string = moment(userDate, "DD.MM.YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    $("#results").html(date_string);
});
```

**MOMENT.JS DEMO: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r42jg/303/)**

Comment: [.getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) should return a `zero-based number` (means from 0 - 11) while yours returns `"11"` http://jsfiddle.net/8ke27xth/1/ `8D`

Comment: I understand how this is zero-based, just didnt seem to matter since he just wants the month output. In any case, moment.js is a way better approach.

Comment: almost there thanks but for sure i'll need zero for example if month is March then show print 03 and if day fourth should print 04 so result should be 2014-03-04 , thanks

Comment: @nasser ...no, zero based means 0-11 instead of 1-12

Comment: with your code it prints 2014-11-4,  but this is will confuse my search , it has to be 2014-11-04  so i need the zero to show if its a single number

Comment: @nasser Can you not use moment.js? this will save you a lot of pain. I had to create a calendar in the past and I initially did not want to make the move but once I did, I never went back. Dont try to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find you answer here:
[Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Replace the "." with "-" to validate the date.

Edit: this is done in javascript, Jquery does not have a utillity function for date

Comment: Are you refering to the datepicker? If so then Im sorry for missleading, i though he wanted a custom soloution that did not involve datepicker