# Converting date format

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert string `01 January 2016` to `01/01/2016` in jQuery. I am getting date from bootstrap datepicker fields by `$('#datepicker').val()` method. but need to convert date to `dd/mm/yyyy` format for further processing

Comment: FYI jQuery isn't involved in formatting dates. You need plain old JS for that. I've retagged your question for you. Note that it may also help if you stated which datepicker control you're using as it may have built-in date formatting logic. You stated it's one for Bootstrap, but there are literally hundreds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549773/convert-date-format-in-jquery this link will help you.

Comment: i am ujsing bootstrap datepicker

Comment: you can set output format in options of bootstrap datepicker

Comment: There is a format option in bootstrap datepicker: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format

Comment: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: @ajazsiddiqui In that case all the information is in the documentation you just linked to: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format

Answer (score 2):

See this

https://jsfiddle.net/wt7wxn8x/1/

```
var test =  new Date("01 January 2016");
console.log((test.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + test.getDate() + '/' +  test.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com):

```
moment('01 January 2016').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

please add datepicker like this this in your html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
   autoclose: true,
   format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
 });
</script>
```

then get your datepicker value

```
$('#datepicker').val()
```

Comment: i want to appear the date in field as dd/mmm/yyyy  but getting date in dd/mm/yyyy for other purpose

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the format like so.

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    startDate: '-3d'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options,

> Set the `data-date-format` attribute on the input element.

or

> Use the `format` config to set your desired format.

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});

$('#submit-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#display-area').html($('#datepicker-1').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="datepicker-1">Start Date</label>    
    <input class="form-control datepicker" id="datepicker-1" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" aria-describedby="datepickerHelp">
    <small id="datepickerHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Select a date.</small>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary" value="Show Date" />
</form>

<hr />

<strong>Date Value:</strong> <span id="display-area"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Parse to convert string month to corresponding number. please try this one:

```js
let str = "1 January 2016",
    str2 = "1 mar 2016",
    str3 = "1 au 2016";

function cDate(str) {
  if(!(Date.parse(str))) {return 'error';}
  let dt = str.split(' ');    
  let d = new Date(Date.parse(`${dt[1]} ${dt[0]}, ${dt[2]}`));
  let result = `${d.getDate()}/${d.getMonth()+1}/${d.getFullYear()}`;            
  return result;
}

console.log(str, '==', cDate(str));
console.log(str2, '==', cDate(str2));
console.log(str3, '==', cDate(str3));
```